# Restore back-up from pre-encrypted drive into newly encrypted drive

Tags: centos, centos7, luks, dmcrypt

It sounds like I am going to be reinstalling CentOS 7 on a server this weekend.

The original installation didn't have the drive encrypted and it needs to be done. My understanding is that this will require a reformat so was going to back-up with `rsync` to a USB drive and restore after the fresh install and the drive being encrypted.

Is this permitted? Just wasn't sure if CentOS will allow a complete back-up from a un-encrypted file system to restored to an encrypted one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CentOS doesn't care what the source media you are reading your backups from is as long as it can read it.